# How do you in Python typehint a list of union of two classes as a argument

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to create a function that accepts a list of mammels or a list of animals as an arg.

This is my code

```
from typing import Union, List
class Animals():
    pass
class Mammels(Animals):
    pass

def add_mammel(x : List[Union[Animals, Mammels]]):
    x.append(Mammels())

l = [Mammels(), Mammels()]
add_mammel(l)
print(l)
```

This code works but when I check this with mypy i Get the following

```
python -m mypy fourth.py
fourth.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "add_mammel" has incompatible type "List[Mammels]"; expected "List[Union[Animals, Mammels]]"
fourth.py:11: note: "List" is invariant -- see http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance
fourth.py:11: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
```

The problem has something to do with 'variance' but I cant figure out what that really means.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is indeed variance. If you don't know what that means, read [this part of the `mypy` docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#variance-of-generics).

When `mypy` analyzes your code, it's inferring the type of `l` to be `List[Mammels]`, which is a narrower type than `List[Union[Animals, Mammels]]`, since the latter can contain `Animals` objects. The annotation of your function suggests that the ability of the list to contain `Animals` is important, so it says that there's an error when you're passing in a more restricted type.

As suggested by [the documentation page linked in the error message](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance), one easy fix is to explicitly annotate the type of `l` so that it matches what the function suggests:

```
 l: List[Union[Animals, Mammels]] = [Mammels(), Mammels()]
```

You can't benefit from the alternative suggestion of using `Sequence` instead of `List` because your function is mutating the list that is passed in to you (and `Sequence` is an immutable type).

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the correct way to do it in Python3.10

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

AnimalsInherited = TypeVar('AnimalsInherited', bound='Animals', covariant=True)

def add_mammal(x : Type[AnimalsInherited]):
    x.append(Mammals())
```